# Multi Node Cluster Hadoop Setup

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

**Pseudo-Distributed single node cluster implementation**

I am using **window 7 with CYGWIN and installed hadoop-1.0.3** successfully. I still start services job tracker,task tracker and namenode on port (localhost:50030,localhost:50060 and localhost:50070).I have completed single node implementation.

Now I want to implement Pseudo-Distributed multiple node cluster . I don't understand how to divide in master and slave system through network ips?

Comment: hai ruchi, I am to trying to do same, even in single node itself getting issue, im following http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html, could please help me or share the set up tutorial for both configuration

Comment: hii, if u have any regarding single node plz asked me and you have also follow : http://ruchi0711.blogspot.in/2013/04/hadoop-implementationsetup-with-window.html

Comment: thanks Ruchi, i ll start with single node. are you still trying for cluster node?   jai hind ;)

Comment: hadoop which version you used? is it fine doing with 1.2.0

Comment: I am using hadoop-1.0.3 and hbase 0.94. yes afcause its fine but just check compatability.

Answer (score 1):

For your ssh problem just follow the link of single node cluster :

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

and yes, you need to specify the ip's of master and slave in conf file 
for that you can refer this url :
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create number of VM you want to add in your cluster.Make sure that those VM are having the same hadoop version .
Figure out the IPs of each VM.
you will find files named master and slaves in $HADOOP_HOME/conf mention the IP of VM to conf/master file  which you want to treat as master and and do the same with conf/slaves
with slave nodes IP.

Make sure these nodes are having Passwordless-ssh connection.
Format your namenode and then run start-all.sh.

Thanks,

Comment: thanx for answer. Actually i have two system in same n/w using ips(192.167.1.1 and 192.167.1.2) and system name hadop@master and hadoo@slave. I am doing same work as u sad but problem is slave access master machine but master gave exception(ssh:connect to host slave-pc port 22: Connection timed out) . I am also chk port 22 is running plz suggest now whats the problem.I am following the tutorial  http://hayesdavis.net/2008/06/14/running-hadoop-on-windows/

Comment: Its a ssh configuration problem. Make sure that id_dsa.pub of hadoop@master must be copied in hadoop@slaves .ssh/authorized_keys and vice-versa. that simply means .ssh/authorized_keys of both machine looks same.

Comment: sir when i copy id from master to slave it gives (ssh:connect to host slave-pc port 22: Connection timed out) but when copy id from slave to master it works properly and connection establish. we can switch through command(ssh hadoop@master). plz suggest what the problem in master pc so it gives connection prob.

Comment: You are able to connect master from slave then connect it and replace the master's .ssh/authorized_keys file with slave's .ssh/authorized_keys. It will work for sure.

Comment: sir as u say i a doing right now again its working in slave machine but master machine gave exception :                             hadoop@hadoop-master ~
$ scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub hadoop@hadoop-slave:~/.ssh/master-key.pub
ssh: connect to host hadoop-slave port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection

Comment: i am changing master and slave ips in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file...is it important to write master and slave ips in conf/master and conf/slaves files?

Comment: In C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  you can assign name for your ips e.g. Your file looks like 192.167.1.1 master and in next line 192.167.1.2 slave . this tells that u can use master to identify 192.167.1.1 .You have to make changes in conf/master and conf/slaves it is necessary.